# WCMS in PHP or Java (for java developers)?

Tags: java, php, content-management-system, joomla, dotcms

In my company, we're a java developer team. For a project, we need to choose a web content management system (wcms) first. Can we choose a php one ? will we then have to learn php because our customer has some particular demands so we're likely to have to plug our own features...

or can we add our plugins in java and find a way to connect them ? and is it common to do that ? 
we can't afford to learn php considering the time we have

do you think we'd better turn towards java cms ?
In that case, did any of you experience dotcms, I read some good reviews..

thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a CMS written in PHP to execute a Java plugin isn't impossible, but I wouldn't really recommend it. Try visiting http://cmsmatrix.org to help you compare different CMSes on many different feature sets to find one that will work best for you.